# Realm not update existing data in ONE-MANY Relationship Android

Tags: android, realm, realm-java

I have been using realm about more than a years, in many cases realm is good choice to construct Android database instead using SQLite. I have been using realm for one-one, one-many relationship and good for it. But, a moment a good. I discover realm NOT update my existing data in ONE-MANY relationship. This what i have done.

This code for populate skeleton data or a unit test

```
private void initData() {
    List<PackModel> packs = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        PackModel packModel = new PackModel();
        packModel.id = i;
        packModel.name = "Pack " + new Random().nextInt(100);

        List<FoodModel> foods = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            FoodModel foodModel = new FoodModel();
            foodModel.id = 0; // i set primary key 0, so in list should be 3 but when insert should be JUST one
            foodModel.packId = i;
            foodModel.name = "Food " + new Random().nextInt(100);
            foodModel.stock = new Random().nextInt(100);
            foodModel.price = new Random().nextInt(100);
            foodModel.image = "hrrp";
            foodModel.calorie = new Random().nextInt(100);
            foodModel.createTime = System.nanoTime();
            foods.add(foodModel);
        }
        packModel.foods.addAll(foods);
        packs.add(packModel);
    }

    insertdb(packs);
}
```

As you see a List of PackModel, and each PackModel have their food items.
So, i write in Realm like below code.

```
private void insertdb(final List<PackModel> items) {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<PackObject>>() {
        @Override
        protected List<PackObject> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            final List<PackObject> packsObject = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
                PackObject packObject = new PackObject();
                packObject.id = items.get(i).id;
                packObject.name = items.get(i).name;

                List<FoodObject> foodsObject = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int j = 0; j < items.get(i).foods.size(); j++) {
                    FoodObject foodObject = new FoodObject();
                    foodObject.id = items.get(i).foods.get(j).id;
                    foodObject.name = items.get(i).foods.get(j).name;
                    foodObject.createdTime = items.get(i).foods.get(j).createTime;

                    foodsObject.add(foodObject);
                }
                packObject.foods.addAll(foodsObject);
                packsObject.add(packObject);
            }

            Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(RealmApplication.getRealmConfiguration());
            realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                    realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(packsObject);
                }
            });

            return realm.copyFromRealm(realm.where(PackObject.class).findAll());

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<PackObject> items) {
            super.onPostExecute(items);
            Log.d("Test", "");
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

I got multiple FoodObject in each PackObject, what i am wrong here? i also use realm.beginTransaction. realm.beginTransaction is just a same like execute*, the difference just execute* are thread safe.

i also use realm.insertOrUpdate(obj), but just have same result.

***NOTE: I have read realm documentation about it. So dont judge me not read their documentation.***

this my repot for the code https://github.com/radityagumay/realm-bug

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Code sample is missing yo

Comment: i just edit. kindly see ya

Comment: Should be `RealmList` instead of array list

Comment: i also use a RealmList @EpicPandaForce but same result

Comment: Your models should have `RealmList` instead of `List`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce kindly see my git https://github.com/radityagumay/realm-bug

Comment: yes, i also use like this  final RealmList<PackObject> packsObject = new RealmList<>(); but it just have wrong result

Comment: i have no idea where wrong

Comment: Setting the primary key for all object to the same value (0), will leave you with lesser objects than expected. Calling `copyToRealmOrUpdate()`, you will be overwriting/update the first object.

Comment: @geisshirt kindly check my code. i use copyToRealmOrUpdate

Comment: @radityagumay Yes, I saw that. And when the field of the primary key has same value, the first object will be updated (and not copied), and you will have only one object in the end.

Comment: @geisshirt kindly run code, that will keep insert new one, i have no idea whats went wrong

Comment: You create three objects with different (unique primary keys) so you get three Realm object?

Comment: same primary key, i got three object in realm list @geisshirt. kindly check my git code